# How to use insert extension for more than one value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, sorting

I am trying to insert 2 values into the 'extensionsofArcGIS' variable as you can see below, just not sure how to insert more than one at a time? I have tried a few different variations but still no luck..

```
extensionsofArcGIS = ['3D Analyst', 'Spatial Analyst', 'Geostatistical Analyst','Network Analyst', 'ArcScan']

extensionsofArcGIS.insert(1,'Terrain Editor')(2, 'Test')

extensionsofArcGIS.sort()

print extensionsofArcGIS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the values of a list into a Python list, use the `extend` method.

e.g.

```
extensionsofArcGIS = ['3D Analyst', 'Spatial Analyst', 'Geostatistical Analyst','Network Analyst', 'ArcScan'] 
extensionsofArcGIS.extend(['Terrain Editor', 'Test'])
extensionsofArcGIS.sort()
print extensionsofArcGIS
```

Here are a few answers that go into detail on `extend`:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend